# TypeScript фильтрация данных .filter

Tags: массивы, typescript, filter

Как мне отфильтровать массив в TypeScript? 
Пробовал так

```
    findAllPersonsNotVisited():Observable<Person[]> {

    var rightNow = new Date();
    var res = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"-");




    return this.db.list('person/' + res)
        **.filter(
          person => person.isVisitor === false
        )**
        .do(console.log)
        .map(Person.fromJsonList);

}
```

Также в блоке

```
    ngOnInit() {
  this.allPersonsIsVisited = this.allPersons.filter(
          person => person.isVisited === false);
}
```

И всегда пустой массив, хотя должно было отфильтровать.

Comment: Как выглядет ваш класс `Person` ?

Comment: А у вас после фильтра ещё две функции подключены?

Comment: А вообще такие вещи вещи нужно дебажить - ставить брейкпоинты и смотреть на значения переменных. Хорошо дебажить в вебшторме или в браузере